# hello, how can i modify this assembly code to print sum from 5 - 10. It currently prints from 1 to 10. Can any assembly programmer help me?

Tags: assembly, sum

```
title Summation 
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg db "Sum of numbers from 1 to 10 : $"
.code
main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    lea dx,msg
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ax,0
    mov cx,10
AGAIN:
    add ax,cx
    loop AGAIN

    call writeint   ;Display AX as a decimal integer

    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h
main endp

writeint proc
    push ax ;Save used registers
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx

    test ax,8000h   ;Test negative?
    jz L3
    mov dl,'-'
    push ax
    mov ah,2
    int 21h     ;Put - sign
    pop ax
    neg ax      ;Get 2's complement

L3: 
    mov cx,0
    mov bx,10   ;Write decimal
L1:
    mov dx,0
    div bx
    add dx,'0'
    push dx     ;Store digit
    inc cx
    cmp ax,0
    jne L1

    mov ah,2    ;Print char
L2:
    pop dx      ;Restore digit
    int 21h
    loop L2

    pop dx  ;Restore registers to previous values
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
writeint endp

end main
```

Comment: Get a pencil and a paper and trace the algorithm (the main proc). You wil see that something interesting happens with two registers involved.

Comment: when i trace it, i get the sum of 1 to 10. i made a change 0 to 5 and it gave  me  sum of 60. why is that? what changes will give sum of 5 - 10? im a basic learner of the language

Comment: Don't trace it with the debugger. Trace it with pencil and paper, knowing what each instruction does.

Comment: think i found solution, i did what you said by knowing what each instruction does. the value in ax register is added to total sum of number in range of (0-10) which is 55. so when i put mov ax, -10, it works

Comment: i want to try something new. how would i go about modifying it to sum even numbers between 0 and 20 and print the sum.

Comment: Check what LOOP does and add apropiate instructions so the register that is used to be added to the accumulator only goes on even numbers

Comment: how do i use conditional statements to get sum of even numbers between 0 and 20.

Comment: Another hint: You don't compute the sum of 1 to 10, you compute the sum of 10 to 1. And `cx` starts at 10 and exits the `loop` when reaching 0. Now *you* figure out how to go from 10 to 5, instead of from 10 to 1.

Comment: @Bo Persson, you are right, what i found out is that ax holds the sum counting from 10 going down. so if i put in a jump when cx is less than 5 to jump to  call writeint   ;Display AX as a decimal integer, it prints out sum 10 to 5.

Comment: You could avoid the loop and be creative and compute the sum between the range of 5 to 10 using simple algebra. if n = lower bound and you want to sum from n to n+5 then you'd have n+(n+1)+(n+2)+(n+3)+(n+4)+(n+5) = 6n+15 . If n=5 then the sum from 5 to 10 is 6*5+15 = 45.

Comment: Of course this can be generalized by using the formula for the sum of an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: @MichaelPetch you are also logical here in another way to solve the problem. what i am trying though is to solve the sum of even numbers from 0 - 20. I was trying using mod operator to test if a number in cx register  is even then total them up within the range 0 - 20

Comment: @JohnnyCage You should ask __a different question__ to solve your new issue concerning even values in the range 0-20. Do accept the answer to your current question and move on with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Bo Persson, you are right, what i found out is that ax holds the sum counting from 10 going down. so if i put in a jump when cx **is less than 5** to jump to call writeint ;Display AX as a decimal integer, it prints out sum 10 to 5

From your last comment I see that you almost found it yourself. But if you jump out when CX is less than 5 you will already have added **4** to the sum! So it's better to jump out when CX equals 5.

```
 mov  ax,0
 mov  cx,10
AGAIN:
 add  ax,cx
 cmp  cx, 5
 je   EXIT
 loop AGAIN
EXIT:
```